# Airplane mode not working in Android 4.3 S3?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have tried with 4.2  and 5.0 as well that mode is working fine, When i started testing on `S3 4.3 i got following error`.

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS flg=0x10000000 }
```

Intent which i have used to get the **airplane setting mode** is.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS);
                  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Please let me know is their any other way to do.

Comment: can you post your manifest ?

Comment: Individual device vendors can customize Android. They will often provider their own phone dialers, messaging apps, settings apps, etc. Unless you are running on stock Android, you can't expect these things will be there. Samsung likes to add a lot of customization to their Android phones. In this case you need to catch the `ActivityNotFoundException` and just tell the user to enable/disable Airplane mode. All this code does is start a "Settings" activity anyway. The user still has to enable/disable it manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {
    try {
        Intent intentAirplaneMode = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS);
        intentAirplaneMode.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intentAirplaneMode);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("exception", e + "");
    }
} else {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent("android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS");
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

try this code hope it will work.